# How to plot a bar plot by ggplot2 and sort bars in non-alphabetical order

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to plot a boxplot by `ggplot2` and it sorts the boxes in alphabetical order, but I want to change their order. How can I do that?

Thanks for any help.

Here is my code:

```
mydata <- data.frame(DRG=c(12,23,15,60,2),
                     XPA=c(30,25,55,70,63),
                     SHO=c(22,15,34,23,14),
                     ALA=c(120,95,113,126,103))
row.names(mydata) <- c("sample1","sample2","sample3","sample4","sample5")
mydata <- t(mydata)
mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)

b.plot <- ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=row.names(mydata), y=sample1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity" , color="green" , fill="yellowgreen", position="dodge" , width = 0.5) +
  xlab("Genes") +
  ylab("Expression") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        plot.margin = margin(0.5,0.5,0.5,2, "cm"))
b.plot
```

Comment: Just as a note: `fct_relevel` is not provided as an answer in those sites indicated as duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `fct_relevel` from `forcats` package (it is in `tidyverse`).

1. Bring your rownames to a column `gene` with `rownames_to_column` function from `tibble` package (it is in `tidyverse`)
2. Use `fct_relevel` to set the order as you wish
3. Then use `ggplot2` (I used `geom_col()`)

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>% 
  rownames_to_column("gene") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -gene
  ) %>% 
  mutate(gene = fct_relevel(gene, 
                            "SHO", "DRG", "ALA", "XPA")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=gene, y=value))+
  geom_col(color="green" , fill="yellowgreen", position="dodge" , width = 0.5)+
  xlab("Genes")+
  ylab("Expression") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        plot.margin = margin(0.5,0.5,0.5,2, "cm"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set `x` to be a factor, then use `levels` to set the order that you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = factor(
  row.names(mydata),
  levels = c("DRG", "XPA", "SHO", "ALA")
), y = sample1)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity" ,
    color = "green" ,
    fill = "yellowgreen",
    position = "dodge" ,
    width = 0.5
  ) +
  xlab("Genes") +
  ylab("Expression") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      size = 10,
      angle = 45,
      hjust = 1
    ),
    plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2, "cm")
  )
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Dear Andrew, thanks for your reply. 
I've converted `x` to a factor and only labels were changed, but I want to reorder the **boxes** with **their** **labels** and not only the labels.

Comment: Andrew, you need to set levels

Comment: @zahraabdi I meant `levels`, not `labels`. I've updated the answer to reflect that. Sorry,  it was late!